# Xamarin Essentials Android Contacts: is there a way to determine which phone number? EG: Home, Work, Mobile?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin Essentials Contacts: is there a way to determine which phone number is which?  EG: Home, Work, Mobile?

This is just for Android only.

Currently it just has the phone number(s) only, but I have a need to only display *Mobile* phone numbers (for SMS) and I can't see a way to determine if a number is tagged as 'Mobile'.  Like when you create a contact on your andriod phone, you can set the phone number to be Home, Mobile, Work, etc.

Or anyone know of another library that does this?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let take the example from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/contacts). You could use the property `ContactType` of type enum `ContactType`, but it only defines `Unknown`, `Personal` and `Work` values:

```
try
{
    var contact = await Contacts.PickContactAsync();

    if(contact == null)
        return;

    var phones = contact.Phones; // List of phone numbers
    foreach (var phone in phones)
    {
        if (phone.ContactType == ContactType.Personal || phone.ContactType == ContactType.Work) //just an example
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle exception here.
}
```